Running an API through a powershell script and getting the answer: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send
I am trying to run an API using a post method through a powershell script
Here is the code:
$username = "###"
$password = "###"

# Create the body of the request as a hashtable
$body = @{
    "tenancyName" = "###"
    "usernameOrEmailAddress" = $username
    "password" = $password
}

# Create a hashtable for the request headers
$headers = @{
    "Content-Type" = "application/json"
}
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
$Token = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post '###' -Headers $headers -Body $body
Write-Output $Token

As an answer all I get is this answer:

Invoke-RestMethod : The underlying connection was closed: An
unexpected error occurred on a send. At
C:\Users\Ngoel\Desktop\fileTrigger\test.ps1:26 char:10

$Token = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post 'https://...

     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-RestMethod],
WebException
FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand*




As you can see I try to use Tls12 protocol already as I have seen other tickets proposing this as a solution.
By the way my .Net version is 5.0.101 so I think Tls12 is supported by default anyway.
I would really appreciate some help
Thanks
